# Powershell pattern match for last few records and filename for each result

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I am super new to Powershell and need some info or guidance on the following scenario. I have some files in a folder and I want to user Powershell to look at them and if they are one day old then extract last few lines until it sees a specific pattern. Output should be in a text file and I want to include the file name for each result.

I was able to write a script to get to the files and extract last 2 lines and put it in an output file. I don't know how to do a pattern match and make the script only grab lines until it sees pattern "---(S3B" and also include the file name for each result in the output file. Any help is appreciated.

Example of files and data

**File 1: ABC_1.txt**

aaaaaa

bbbbbb

---(s3B

cccccc

dddddd

---(s3B

eeeee

fffff

**File 2: ABC_2.txt**

ggg

aaaaaa

---(s3B

oooooo

ABC_3.txt

ppppp

---(s3B

aaaaaa

**File 3: XYZ_1.txt**

yyyyyy

---(s3B

rrrrrrr

cccccc

---(s3B

sssssss

qqqqqqq

**Desired output in file**

ABC_1.txt

cccccc

dddddd

ABC_2.txt

oooooo

ABC_3.txt

aaaaaa

XYZ_1.txt

sssssss

qqqqqqq

Example Script that is looking back x number of days based on my input and its grabbing 2 lines. How can I make it grab last few rows and stop at the pattern ---(s3B and also include file name for each result in my output file.

```
$path = "C:\Test"
$files = Get-ChildItem $path -recurse -Include *.txt | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -gt "$date" } 
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")

foreach ($file in $files) {get-content $file | select  -Last 2  |out-file $Results -append }

$Results = "C:\Test\$($file.name).txt"
```

Sample result from the script created in output file

cccccc

dddddd

---(s3B

oooooo

---(s3B

aaaaaa

sssssss

qqqqqqq

Answer (score 1):

I was also thinking about Select-String, but I'm unaware of how to focus it only on the last 2 lines.  You can Get-Content first and pipe it to Select-String, but then I'm not sure how you'd stop outputting when the match is found.  -Context will give the surrounding lines regardless.  I worked this out the hard way, but I hope I'm wrong (grin) :

```
$path = "C:\Temp"
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$files = Get-ChildItem $path -recurse -Include *.txt | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -gt $date }
$Pattern = "Server Failures"
$OutputFile = "C:\Temp\SomeOutput.txt"

foreach ($file in $files)
{    
    $Results = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

    :Inner ForEach( $Line in (get-content $file -tail 2) ) 
    {
        If( $Line -match $Pattern )
        {
            [Void]$Results.Add($Line)
            Break Inner
        }
        Else
        {
            [Void]$Results.Add($Line)
        } 
    }

    If( $Results )
    {
        ( $File.Name + ":") | Out-File $OutputFile -Append
        $Results | Out-File $OutputFile -Append
    }
}
```

I had to change some things just to test in my environment with files I had on hand, but that should be obvious for you.  I'm not thrilled with this, but I think it'll work.

Let me know what you think.  If you need a walk through on how it works etc...

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Select-String` with the `-Context` switch is probably the way to go. Example below but not tested:

```
$path = "C:\Test"
$date = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-1)
Get-ChildItem $path -recurse -Include *.txt | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -gt $date} | Select-String -Pattern '---(S3B' -Context 2, 0 | % {
    $f = $_.Filename
    $_.Context.PreContext | % {"{0} -> {1}" -f $f, $_}
} | Out-File $Results
```